# How to install Android App to internal sdcard or how to utilize the internal storage

Tags: android, internal

My partition of data's space is lack,So I move the app from data to internal sdcard, the phone deny this option. Now I move app to external sdcard,and my internal sdcard only use 1% and I do not know how to utilize it,my photos store in my external sdcard.

After I delete partition 18(/data) and 19(/storage/sdcard1) and recreate them,the phone can not start up.

After I move `/data/data to /system/data` and link `/system/data to /data/data`,the phone can not start up.

After I move `/data/dalvik-cache` to `/system/dalvik-cache` and link `/system/dalvik-cache` to `/data/dalvik-cache`,the phone can not start up.

After I move `/data/app` to `/system/data_app/app` and link `/system/data_app/app` to `/data/app`,the phone can start up,but all the app can not upgrade.And I can not debug my developed app in my phone.

Now I move some apk from `/data/app` to `/system/app`,some app can not work,I have to move them back.Some app can work normal,but when the app update,the size of /data still decrease.

How can I use my internal sdcard or how can I store all my app in my phone's internal storage,I don't want setup the app to external sdcard.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [FAQ HELP](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Is this related to programming ?

Comment: Would it be possible to link `/data/app` to `/storage/sdcard0/whatever` to fix `Insufficient storage available` problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your **Android Manifest** file

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

or

```
android:installLocation="auto".
```

Comment: I don't want to install the app to external sdcard.I want to know how to install all the app to the phone when there is not enough space in /data.But there are large space in /cache,/system or internal sdcard.